# Besides Skim, what OSX PDF viewers support SyncTeX?

Tags: pdf, latex

I hope this question is not a duplicate. I use a lot of pdfLaTeX in my daily work on OSX (10.8). I've been using Skim and its SyncTeX support to preview PDFs and link forward and backward and that's fine. There are a bunch of PDF viewers on OSX and I'm wondering if others also support SyncTeX (commercial or not). I tend to prefer standalone editors and previewers instead of integrated environments such as TeXShop, but I'd like to hear about all types of PDF viewers that offer SyncTeX support. I'm not finding that this information is easily accessible on the web so answers to this question might serve as a handy reference.

For starters, it seems the standard OSX Preview doesn't support SyncTeX. Is that correct?

Comment: See [Forward/inverse search for Texmaker on OS X](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9904)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using macports you can install okular:

```
port install okular
```

Consider editing the port file if you want to use kile (KDE's TeX editor) as well, as it depends on texlive and most mac users already have a TeXlive installation through MacTeX:

```
port edit kde4-kile
#remove the line which contains texlive
port install kde4-kile
```

After installing okular (and optionally kile) open okular and go to Settings > Configure Okular > Editor and insert the command to start your favorite editor( `%f` stands for the path, `%l` for the line). This question on [tex.so](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-to-set-up-inverse-search-with-okular-and-kile) describes the setup for kile.

Finally click on any part of the PDF while holding shift to use reverse sync.

Answer (score 1):

The SyncTex page offers a SyncTex Viewer. Its a free app and works fine on regular PDFs.

Answer (score -2):

A popular non-free option is [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/). It supports SyncTEx.

Comment: Please read the question.

Comment: @Dominique fair enough. Might be good to mention Skim in the title though - others in tl;dr mode will come here looking for an osk pdf viewer and will easily miss Sikim as a viable option.

Comment: @Dominique might be an idea to accept a few answers to your questions, you've some quality answers there I see that could perhaps be accepted (: